# Cannot integrate function with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, integral, calculus

I've been trying to integrate functions with SymPy in Python, but some are not evaluating properly. There've been two problematic scenarios that have been occurring for me:

1. 'expr not of form a*x**b: %s' -- one example of this is with

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
f = 1 / (25 + x**2)**(3/2)
print(integrate(f, x))
```

2. Outputs a weird result that is not the answer. One example is

```
from sympy import *
x, a = symbols('x a')
f = 1 / (a**2 + x**2)
print(integrate(f, x))
```

In this case, the output is `(-I*log(-I*a + x)/2 + I*log(I*a + x)/2)/a` which is definitely not the correct answer of `atan(x/a)/a` that it should return.

How can each of these issues be addressed? Thanks.

Comment: Try `Rational(3,2)` instead of `3/2`.  And specify `real=True` for the symbols.

Comment: Case 1 is a bug triggered by using floats: with Rational(3, 2) it works. For case 2 the answer given is correct just in terms of log rather than atan. If you make the symbols  real then it gives `atan(x/a)/a`.

Comment: Thanks guys, it resolved the problem.